# UILexiconで普通の辞書データを取得したい。

Tags: swift

UILexiconの[クラスリファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILexicon_Class/)を見ると、3種類のデータ（アドレス帳、ユーザー定義辞書、普通の辞書）を取得できると書いてあります。

しかし、アドレス帳とユーザー定義辞書のデータは取得できますが、一般の辞書データが取得できません。
[こちらのページ](http://dev.classmethod.jp/references/ios8-uilexicon/)などでも、同じ状態が報告されています。

普通のiPhone辞書データベースから、漢字候補などを取得するには、何か特別な設定があるのでしょうか。どなたかお教えいただければ幸いです。

ちなみに、私が書いているコードはこのような感じです。アドレス帳とユーザー辞書からのデータのみが返ってきます。

```
    self.requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion({
        lexicon in
        // UILexicon から取得したデータを表示
        for item in lexicon.entries {
            // 検索結果
            if(hira == item.userInput ){
                // 検索結果とマッチしたユーザー入力値
                if(countHere < 2){//ユーザー辞書からの取得数制限
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                        self.candidates.append(item.documentText)
                        self.candidateLabels[countHere].text = item.documentText
                        countHere += 1
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

よろしくお願い致します。

━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

追記：英語版のstack overflowの回答で、役に立つかもしれない情報がありましたので、[リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052764/how-to-use-auto-suggestion-view-for-custom-key-board-extension-ios8)を残します。役に立つかどうか、まだわかりません。

━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

追記2：英語版で、さらに情報を探してみました。こちらの[リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709388/keyboard-extension-no-common-words-no-autocorrect)が役に立ちそうでした。まだ自分では実装してみていません。UITextCheckerクラスの使用について。日本語が対応しているかどうか。。

追記3：日本語がUITextCheckerクラスに対応しているか調べました。
2016年9月23日現在、対応していません。対応言語は以下でした。
[en_CA, pt_BR, it_IT, ko_KR, nb_NO, de_DE, en_GB, sv_SE, en_AU, en_SG, es_MX, pt_PT, en_IN, fr_FR, es_ES, nl_NL, tr_TR, fi_FI, pl_PL, ru_RU, en_US, da_DK]